# Mixing .Net Framework app with .Net Core library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, compatibility

In a Visual Studio solution, I need to have a desktop winforms application project (.Net framework 4.0) depending on a .Net Core library project.
I can't migrate the application to .Net core yet, but I need functionalities from .Net core (ie Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore). That's why I created a new project as a dependency.

It seems to cause a problem at build time:

*Reference to type 'Object' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found*

Idem with *DateTime*, *Enum*, *Decimal*, ...

As if object wasn't the same in both project.
I tried to use Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility but it doesn't seem to be a solution.

Is there a way to have both projects build and run together?

**EDIT 1**

I tried with a .Net standard project instead of .Net core, but in this case I can't even add a reference from .Net framework app to .Net standard library.

*Project "Std.csproj" targets "netstandard2.0", it can't be referenced by a project that targets ".NetFramework,Version=v4.0"*

**EDIT 2**

I still get the same error with my dependency in .Net core 2.0 and my app in .Net Framework 4.6:

*Project "Std.csproj" targets "netstandard2.0", it can't be referenced by a project that targets ".NetFramework,Version=v4.6"*

**EDIT 3**

I finally got rid of the error with .Net Framework 4.6.1. But, according to [required configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements) for this framework, it means I can't deploy to Windows XP anymore. To study...

As my goal is to migrate gradually to .Net Core, any advice is welcome.

Comment: No. If you want to share code, create a .NET Standard library. [EF Core 3.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.2) *works with .NET Old* though - it's a .NET Standard 2.0 package. You probably need to upgrade your EF Core version.

Comment: Yeah. EfCore 3.1 is supposedly (never tested it) compatible with NetStandard 2.0

Comment: @TomTom it's the package's target. It couldn't use higher-version classes even if someone tried

Comment: Well, at some point technology does not care what you want. There is no way to do what you want (use a .net core assembly in a .net project) so you something must give. "I can not" results in "you can not do what you want".

Comment: Wait - `.NET 4.0` is unsupported for many years now. It never got any kind of .NET Standard support - it can't, as it doesn't even support `async/await`. You need to upgrade to .NET 4.6.1, preferably .NET 4.7.2 to avoid problems with compatibility libraries.

Comment: Preferably 4.7.2 or 4.8 if you don't like fun assembly binding exceptions.

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) : `For .NET Framework projects that need to use such libraries, we recommend that you upgrade the project to target .NET Framework 4.7.2 or higher`

Comment: BTW given that .NET 4.x runtimes are binary replacements, the application is *already* running on .NET 4.5+ for many years now. Simply installing a new runtime for another application, or a Windows Update would replace the existing runtime. The *only* OS where that can't happen is Windows XP, which is also unsupported for many years now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to have a [...] .Net framework 4.0 depending on a .Net Core library project.
>
> Is there a way to have both projects build and run together?

## No

Sorry. That's not the way it works. You cannot directly reference a .NET Framework assembly from .NET Core or the other way round a .NET Core assembly from .NET Framework.

<sup>(I have a slight deja vu, I will try to find the duplicate on this).</sup>

What you can do is create a shared assembly in .NET Standard that both can reference, but in this case it would not actually help you, because you would need a higher .NET Framework version to be able to use .NET Standard 2.0.

What would work is creating a connection between your assemblies that is not a direct assembly binding via reference. One could call the other via REST over HTTP or via memory mapped files or in any other way that you would use to have two otherwise incompatible technologies communicate.

Comment: EF Core 3.1 is a .NET Standard 2.0 package, so it will work. The real problem is that the OP is targeting .NET 4.0

Comment: "... cannot directly reference a .NET Framework assembly from .NET Core" this is not entirely true, .NET Core does support running some Framework assemblies that target 4.6.1 or below.

Comment: .NET Core can use .NET Old assemblies on Windows. I'm using AlphaFS in my .NET Core apps simply because there's no other way to access advanced NTFS features. You get a warning on every build but the assembly works

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is that really what you would recommend? That people use technology "because a specific subset happens to work on my machine right now"? The documented behavior is as I described it. I will not recommend glitches or what would otherwise be described as "Undefined behavior" in C++. Sure, it might work in certain specific cases, but that's not the standard of quality I expect from SO answers.

Comment: The documented behaviour [allows for some references from Core to Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-2-0#support-for-net-framework-libraries).

Comment: @yaakov Hm, interesting, so if something is standard without advertising it, it will work anyway. Good to know, thanks for the link. I still think that while you are technically right, that blanket statement of "it does not work that way" is probably a good answer, otherwise you'd have to rely on a programmer accidentally using standard only. That's not really a good position to be in, hoping that somebody else is right by pure random chance.

Comment: @nvoigt no, [because the .NET/VS teams explicitly added that support in .NET 2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/606). It's not ideal, but for many cases there's no alternative yet.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I learned something new today. Sometimes you have no other chance it seems. But I'd still say for someone who wants to "gradually migrate to :NET Core" it's not a good idea to let lady luck decide and just hope for the best (in his case someone by chance no using anything outside standard).

Comment: Depends on the assembly. If it's a PCL assembly, depending on the profile it may be 100% safe...

Answer (score 3):

The .NET Framework version must be at least 4.6 in order to reference a .NET Standard project or nuget package.

Additionally, you will need Visual Studio 2017 or newer to be able to use the reference. Visual Studio 2015 will not work.

Comment: The practical minimum is `4.7.2`. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) : `For .NET Framework projects that need to use such libraries, we recommend that you upgrade the project to target .NET Framework 4.7.2 or higher`

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the only solution. .NET 4.0 is unsupported, it can't use *any* .NET Standard or Core feature. As for Visual Studio, all `Community` editions are free and offer the same features as Professional.

Comment: We have some legacy products using .net standard in a 4.6.2 that's why I answerd it as the minimum.
But I agree 4.7 is the better choice.

Comment: Then you've seen what "fun" it is to fight all those compatibility libraries...

Comment: This answer as written is somewhat misleading. .NET 4.5 and above can use _some_ level of .NET Standard, though you need 4.6.1 minimum (for a volatile app) or 4.7.2 (for a more stable one) to use a .NET Standard 2.0 assembly such as EFCore. There is also some level of tooling available for VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

**YES**, it is possible to use both .net Core and .net Framework within the same process, provided you keep them as quite separate assemblies and you are willing to interact through COM.

An example of how to interact in this way is provided in https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/extensions/NetComSxS .