# How to add vb.net4 dll in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project and how to configure the appsetiings to establish the connection string

Tags: vb.net, .net-6.0, dllimport, dll-reference

I have added the DLL into my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project, but I'm unable to get the data from referenced dll - please provide a solution.

How to establish connection between the referenced VB.net dll with my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project?

And is vb.net4 framework supported by .NET 6?`

Comment: If you want to use a library in both .NET Framework and .NET Core projects, it needs to target .NET Standard. That's exactly what .NETY Standard is for.

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390796/mixing-net-framework-app-with-net-core-library) may or may not be of help.