# Assembly.GetType returns null while using C# Console Application (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, assembly.load, dynamic-dll-import

Why does Assembly.GetType(name) return null when I use C# Console Application (.NET Framework), but not when I use C# Console Application? The code works perfectly when I use C# Console Application.

Following is the code:

```
    Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\MyFolder\MyDLL.dll");
    Type myType = myAssembly.GetType("MyDLL.MyClass");
    MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("MethodInDLL");
```

The code errors at the second line with the error - System.IO.FileNotFoundException:'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03a6g11e6b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The DLL I am trying to invoke is a simple one that prints a message box. Here's what it looks like:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    namespace MyDLL
     {
       public class MyClass
        {
          public static void MethodInDLL()
           {
             MessageBox.Show("Message from DLL file");
           }
        }
    }
```

The .NET version I use is 4.7.2

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question to provide enough info. In this case you need to show how you build that "MyDll" assembly, in particular what framework it targets as creating assembly that successfully loads in both .Net Framework and .Net Core / .Net 5+ requires some [specific steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390796/mixing-net-framework-app-with-net-core-library) that should be shown in the question for everyone to be able to understand where mistake happen.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexeiLevenkov, I've updated the question.